# Tag for (whipping) siphon N2O/CO2 related questions

Tags: feature-request, tags

There is a number of questions about soda siphons / pressurized gas techniques. Maybe there should be a tag for those? I'm not so sure about the name exactly, I think whipping siphon might be the general term?

Answer (score 1):

There has been a tag called [whipper](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/whipper) for a very long time, although it only has 21 questions, so maybe it was difficult to find.

We now also have a tag called [whipping-siphon](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/whipping-siphon), which should come up in searches using the word "siphon" only, and I made [whipper](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/whipper) a synonym of it.